# Query only records with max value within a group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Say you have the following `users` table on PostgreSQL:

```
id | group_id |    name | age
---|----------|---------|----
 1 |        1 |    adam |  10
 2 |        1 |     ben |  11
 3 |        1 | charlie |  12   <-
 3 |        2 |  donnie |  20  
 4 |        2 |    ewan |  21   <-
 5 |        3 |    fred |  30   <-
```

How can I query all columns only from the oldest user per `group_id` (those marked with an arrow)?

I've tried with `group by`, but keep hitting `"users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause`.

(Note: I have to work the query into a Rails AR model scope.)

Comment: I think you can do `User.group(:group_id).select('max(users.age), users.*')` - it will basically tell PostgreSQL to group by `group_id` and select only the user row having the maximum age within each group

Comment: Not really. The resulting SQL is `SELECT max(users.age), users.* FROM "users" GROUP BY "users"."group_id"` which throws the `"users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging, you can do use PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON (col)`:

```
select distinct on (users.group_id) users.*
from users
order by users.group_id, users.age desc;
-- you might want to add extra column in ordering in case 2 users have the same age for same group_id
```

Translated in Rails, it would be:

```
User
  .select('DISTINCT ON (users.group_id), users.*')
  .order('users.group_id, users.age DESC')
```

Some doc about `DISTINCT ON`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Working example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t4jeW4Sy91oxEfjMKYJpB1/0

Comment: Very nice. Not sure whether this is faster or slower than Lukasz' answer (EXPLAIN shows similar results), but I'll accept your answer since you translated it to AR as well, big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER/RANK`(if ties are possible) windowed functions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY age DESC) AS rn
      FROM tab) s
WHERE s.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a subquery wuth aggreagated resul in join

```
select m.* 
from  users m
inner join (
  select  group_id, max(age) max_age
  from users 
  group by group_id
) AS t on (t.group_id = m.group_id and t.max_age  = m.age)
```

Comment: No dice: `"users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause`

Comment: IC, the updated query works, but according to EXPLAIN at a higher cost than the other two answers. Thanks anyways!